# MemSQL: Table is a distributed table. You cannot query it from a leaf

Tags: singlestore

I've installed MemSQL on a single server for testing and have created three tables as described in this example:

[MEMsql - how to run queries](https://docs.memsql.com/v5.8/docs/how-to-run-queries)

I can query the database from within the Memsql client running via ssh without any issues.  However, whenever I try to run the same query programmatically in PHP I get the error "Table 'memsql_example.employees' is a distributed table. You cannot query it from a leaf".

The PHP code that generates that error is below:

```
<?php

  $dbHost="127.0.0.1";
  $dbUser="root";
  $dbPass="";
  $dbName="memsql_example";
  $dbPort=3307;

  // Connect to database
  $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, $dbPort);
  if ($mysqli==false) die ("Error connecting to database\n");

  $sql="select count(*) from employees;";
  $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
  if (!$result) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    die();
  }

?>
```

I've tried running the above script from another server by changing the $dbHost to point to the server IP rather than 127.0.0.1 but without success as I get the same error.

I've stared at this for hours - what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries in MemSQL should be directed against the aggregator, which by default will run on port 3306. It looks like you are querying port 3307, which will be a leaf by default in your configuration.

Comment: Ah thanks Rob, I went for 3307 so that I could run MySQL alongside it which defaults to port 3306.  I'll re-install tomorrow (it's late here) and will test it again

Comment: ahh I see. If you have MySQL running on 3306 then MemSQL won't be able to. Did you change the MemSQL port during installation?

Comment: I've actually put it onto two different machines (one acting as a cluster and the other as a leaf) using 3306 and it worked fine.  I found this tutorial useful as I was impatient and wanted to dive straight in and get on with it.  I've got deadlines looming .... http://blog.programster.org/setup-a-memsql-cluster-in-debian-8/